# Minicart not Updating, after adding products to cart from Requisiiton List on Apple devices

Tags: magento2, minicart

We are having concern, while adding products to cart from the requisition list on Apple devices (Iphone/Ipad).

We are using Magento 2 EE, prems. And it has default Requisition List. So when we add products to cart from Req List, It adds the products to the cart, and updates the cart, when using Chrome or Mozilla. But, when i do it in safari it doesn't update the minicart(product quantity).

This is related to apple devices only. Otherwise working fine.

We tried to update minicart with help of observer, which is call after adding products to cart, but no luck.